# Pandas Concat two dataframes with different amount of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question about pd.concat. I get some weird results and I do not get why.

Let start with a simple example (this should also show what I want to achieve):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[7,6,5]], columns = ["A","B","C"])
print("DF1: \n", df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[4,5,6]], columns = ["A","B","C"])
print("DF2: \n", df2)
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index = True)
print("Concat DF1 and DF2: \n",df3)
```

[image]

Now I have my actual programm where I have DataFrames like this:
[image]

When I am applying the concat function, I get this:

[image]

It makes zero sense to me. What can possible be the reason?

P.S. It's not urgent, because I found a workaround but this bothers me and makes me a bit angry too.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is your desired result, i.e., what do you specifically mean by "combining" two dataframes? Currently, you combine columns for each index (`axis=1`). You could also combine all rows for each column (`axis=0`).

Comment: What is the expected result? Without that the question is unclear and could be closed...

Comment: @harryhaller I want to make it one bigger DataFrame thus the smaller df is added at the end of the bigger df. Like here (what ironically works pretty fine):
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[7,6,5]], columns = ["A","B","C"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[4,5,6]], columns = ["A","B","C"])
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index = True)
I tried both axis 0 and 1 they both give me bs result. What ever the reason is, I really do not care to find out anymore. I found a solution. They're for sure something I overlooked, but honestly, I blame pandas for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for connecting two DataFrame based on their rows

```
Code1) self.teste_df= (self.teste_df).append(test,ignore_index=True)
Code2) pd.concat([self.teste_df, test], axis = 0, ignore_index=True )
```

Comment: Yes I know, I tried it myself before asking the question. That should have worked, but it didn't. I updated the question. You can now see what the result of the Code2 would look like (the last image). That's the issue.

Answer (score -2):

I made them both a list, and combined the lists with `+`.